# Output não esperado no ficheiro (loop infinito) CSV Python

Tags: python, csv

Boas, estou a tentar guardar a distancia e o tempo, resultado da diferença do tempo de envio/chegada do som ultra-sónico, isto através do sensor para Raspberry Pi 3 HC-SR04!

Após obter estes valores que elaborar gráficos com a biblioteca SeaBorn, para para isso preciso queria os dados sejam escritos num ficheiro CSV, mas tal não acontece, o Script fica num loop infinito e substitui sempre os valores na mesma linha, no primeiro segundo o ficheiro pesa 15 bytes no segundo próximo ja pesa 0 bytes, enfim não estou a conseguir fazer com que ele escreva numa nova linha! Sou novo em Python, por isso não sei muito sobre técnicas de loop nem quais metodos utilizar!

Requisitos:

1. Raspberry Pi 3
2. HC-SR04
3. Python 3

O codigo encontra-se aqui em baixo:

```
#Libraries
import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import csv

#GPIO Mode (BOARD / BCM)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

#set GPIO Pins
GPIO_TRIGGER = 23
GPIO_ECHO = 24

#set GPIO direction (IN / OUT)
GPIO.setup(GPIO_TRIGGER, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(GPIO_ECHO, GPIO.IN) 

#set CSV
currentPath = os.getcwd()
csv_files = currentPath + "/data_sensor.csv"
csv_columns = ['Time', 'Distance']

def WriteDictToCSV(csv_files, csv_columns, dict_data):
    new_file = False
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(csv_files):
            new_file = True

        with open(csv_files, 'a+') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
            if new_file:
                writer.writeheader()
            for data in dict_data:
                writer.writerow(data)
    except IOError as err:
        print("I/O error({})".format(err))    

def distance():
    # set Trigger to HIGH
    GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, True)

    # set Trigger after 0.01ms to LOW
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)

    StartTime = time.time()
    StopTime = time.time()

    # save StartTime
    while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO) == 0:
        StartTime = time.time()

    # save time of arrival
    while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO) == 1:
        StopTime = time.time()

    # time difference between start and arrival
    TimeElapsed = StopTime - StartTime
    # multiply with the sonic speed (34300 cm/s)
    # and divide by 2, because there and back
    Distance = (TimeElapsed * 34300) / 2

    return Distance, TimeElapsed

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        try:
            while True:
                d, t = distance()
                dict_data = {t: d}
                WriteDictToCSV(csv_files, csv_columns, dict_data)
                print('Time Elapsed: {} ms | Distance: {} cm'.format(t,d))
                time.sleep(0.5)
        # Reset by pressing CTRL + C
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Measurement stopped by User")
            GPIO.cleanup()
```

Nota: O Script ainda não esta completo, mais dados serão exportados e formatados!

Para quem não possui uma Rpi ou o HC-SR04, aqui esta uma versão minificada do codigo:

```
import os
import csv

currentPath = os.getcwd()
csv_files = currentPath + "/data_sensor.csv"
csv_columns = ['Time', 'Distance']

def WriteDictToCSV(csv_files, csv_columns, dict_data):
    try:
        with open(csv_files, 'a') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
            writer.writeheader()
            for data in dict_data:
                writer.writerow(data)
    except IOError as err:
        print("I/O error({})".format(err))    
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        # "d" respresenta a distancia de 12 cm e "t" representa o tempo em ms
        d, t = 12, 0.14732832
        dict_data = {t: d}
        WriteDictToCSV(csv_files, csv_columns, dict_data)
        #print('Time Elapsed: {} ms | Distance: {} cm'.format(t,d))
```

Output do erro é o seguinte:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/main1.py", line 70, in <module>
    WriteDictToCSV(csv_files, csv_columns, dict_data)
  File "/home/pi/Documents/main1.py", line 34, in WriteDictToCSV
    writer.writerow(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/csv.py", line 153, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/csv.py", line 146, in _dict_to_list
    wrong_fields = [k for k in rowdict if k not in self.fieldnames]
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Sem analisar muito o resto, já digo que você está abrindo o arquivo no modo `w`. Neste modo, o ponteiro sempre é movido ao início do arquivo e o conteúdo atual é sobrescrito. Se quer apenas adicionar, abra o arquivo no modo `a`, pois assim manterá o ponteiro no final do mesmo.

Comment: Você tem bastante código aí que muita gente não vai conseguir reproduzir por não ter uma Raspberry Pi ou o sensor. Pode tentar criar um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) que isole o problema?

Comment: @PedrovonHertwig Acrescentei agora uma versão minificada do codigo!

Comment: @AdersonCarlosWoss , se passar o arquivo para o modo "a" ele ira rescrever o cabeção do ficheiro vezes sem conta!

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Aqui esta, tal como sugerido!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua função para escrever um dicionário não faz muito sentido.

```
def WriteDictToCSV(csv_files, csv_columns, dict_data):
    try:
        with open(csv_files, 'a') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
            writer.writeheader()
            for data in dict_data:
                writer.writerow(data)
    except IOError as err:
        print("I/O error({})".format(err))    
    return
```

Você utiliza como base o `csv.DictWriter`, definindo as colunas `['Time', 'Distance']`. Desta forma, a função de escrita irá esperar um dicionário no seguinte formato:

```
{
    'Time': t,
    'Distance': d
}
```

Mas o que você está passando é `{t: d}`.

Além disso, não vejo porque iterar sobre o dicionário durante a escrita, tal como fez em:

```
for data in dict_data:
    writer.writerow(data)
```

Se `dict_data` for o dicionário como comentado acima, basta fazer `writer.writerow(dict_data)`.

Answer (score 2):

Som - a cada meio segundo esse programa chama a função `WriteDictToCSV` que **destrói** o arquivo gerado meio segundo antes, e grava só os novos dados.

A linha

```
with open(csv_files, 'w') as csvfile:
```

Cria o arquivo novamente, com 0 bytes, cada vez que é executada.

Para um programa desses, você pode deixar o arquivo aberto, e ir gravando incrementalmente os dados, ou abrir o arquivo no modo `"a"` (e não `"w"`), que abre o arquivo para gravação a partir do final, sem destruir o conteúdo anterior.

Tente mudar a função de escrita do arquivo para esta:

```
def WriteDictToCSV(csv_files, csv_columns, dict_data):
    new_file = False
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(csv_files):
             new_file = True

        with open(csv_files, 'a+') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
            if new_file:
                writer.writeheader()
            for data in dict_data:
                writer.writerow(data)
    except IOError as err:
        print("I/O error({})".format(err))
```

(A geração dos dados está incorreta também - você está fazendo bastante confusão com listas e dicionários, e eu recomendo fazer testes, criando listas e dicionários no modo interativo, adicionando valores, apagando valores, explorando os métodos - senão você provavelmente não vai conseguir fazer nada com sentido nesse programa)

Comment: Bom Dia, se me pode-se dar aqui uma ajudinha, ficaria-lhe agradecido! Obrigado

Comment: Oi Micael - a melhor forma de você ter ajuda é fazendo outras perguntas no site.